# How to Remove Content from DatePicker After If is disabled In Jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

What I Need:

- when User Click button Date  in datapicker should be removed .
- url of  that i want after being date disabled :http://postimg.org/image/5wl6p6jod/.
- url of  that i d"nt  want after being date disabled:http://postimg.org/image/4yxcnm1u7/.
- Consider if drop is selected and date is selected and after the  selecting another values of drop down then date picker disabled and date should be clear after being disabled.

  Here is my code:

  ```
             if($("#todo_types").val()=='4')
              {
                $('#dateRangeFrom2').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#dateRangeTo2').prop('disabled',   true);
                }
  ```

Comment: you want hide the element or remove the element ..or clearly tell what do you need

Comment: Do you want to completely destroy the datpicker ?

Comment: i just want reset data if date is disabled

Comment: i have posted images that i want

Comment: Please share the link to the plugin which you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the values from the input boxes you can do something like:

```
if($("#todo_types").val()=='4')
{
$('#dateRangeFrom2').prop('disabled', true);
$('#dateRangeFrom2').val('');
$('#dateRangeTo2').prop('disabled',   true);
$('#dateRangeTo2').val('');
}
```

Comment: Pleasure to help you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the date field you wish to remove the date from and use jQuery to remove the date, as follows

```
$('#selected_date_field').val('');
```

I have done something similar on a project recently and it works fine for me